# PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a procedure giving to it a float parameter, but when I call this procedure with a value like 30.2 it gives to me this error. Any solution?

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure (x in float) as
begin
   insert into my_table values (x);
end;

create table my_table (x float);

execute my_procedure(30.2);
```

Comment: Without sample code -- both of the procedure and of the caller -- there is little anyone can do to help.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: For one thing, you don't need to use the type "float". Just use "number". It handles both ints and floats.

Comment: I used number too, but nothing changed

Comment: Works fine in Oracle 12.1.0.2, in SQL*Plus 11.2 and PL/SQL Developer 11.1.

Comment: The only issue I can see with the code you posted is that you are creating the table AFTER referencing it in the procedure. Obviously that will result in an error, but a very different one (having to do with non-existent table). If you put them in the right order, everything works fine on my installation, which is similar to William Robertson's.

Comment: Nothing changed too, i don't know what to do...

Comment: Two people can't recreate the error using the code you posted. Please post the _actual_ code. More than likely you'll spot the error if you give us the real code.

Comment: If you don't post **a reproducible test case** there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: You need a `/` after the `create procedure` block

Comment: So in SQL Developer ... **1)** you create the table without an error. **2)** you create the procedure without an error. **3)** you run the execute statement exactly as shown and get ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error. You are not using a variable instead? Or a string '30.2'?

Comment: And one doesn't use `FLOAT`, because it is an approximate type, except for the case where you must deal with values exceeding 38 digits - but who does really?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the number instead of float it would work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(x IN NUMBER)    
AS    
BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO my_table     
VALUES    
      (x
      );
END;
CREATE TABLE my_table
    (x NUMBER);

EXECUTE my_procedure(30.2);
```

Comment: It does not work for me, it is as if he considered the parameter 30.2 as a character...